# Returning status code 200 but jQuery ajax reports 404 in IE8

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-browser

The following code works does go into the `success` block in Chrome and FF, but not in IE.

```
jQuery_pinglunla.ajax('http://www.mysite.com',{
                success:function(data){
                        //code
                },
                dataType:'json',
                error:function(e){
                      alert(e.status)
                }
         })
```

I observed the HTTP request and found this request reture **200** code.

However, in IE, the ajax call goes into the `error` block and reports the status code to be **404**.

That is really really strange. What can be the cause of the inconsistancy?

**PS:** 
I am using jQuery 1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

The `404` means the page could not be found, try to set the path of the file you are trying to get:

```
jQuery_pinglunla.ajax('http://www.example.com/index.html', {
  success:function(data){
    //code
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  error: function (e){
    alert(e.status)
  }
})
```

Comment: Yeah, I think he should explicitly define his file, maybe IE has some problem with it.